# SQL join on timestamp differences from the same table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm not sure how to write this SQL query in BigQuery. I have a table of events with names and timestamps. Let's say I have only two events in the table: A and B. What I want to do is query the table to get all instances of event A, and get the next closest occurrence of B and create a new column with the time difference. B will always happen after A.

For example if I had a table that looks like:

```
A1 | 1:00 pm
B5 | 2:00 pm
A3 | 3:00 pm
B9 | 5:00 pm
```

My resultant table would be:

```
A1 | 1 hour
A3 | 2 hours
```

The query I came up with is the following:

```
SELECT
CAST(TIMESTAMP_DIFF((SELECT MIN(sub.time)
FROM table sub
WHERE sub.time > main.time), main.time, SECOND) AS INT64) duration 
FROM table main
```

This works fine for getting the table I wanted above, but I would also like to include an additional column from the subquery. Something that looks like:

```
A1 | 1 hour  | B5Column
A3 | 2 hours | B9Column
```

I attempted at using the query below:

```
SELECT
(SELECT
 sub.SubQueryColumn
 FROM table sub
 WHERE sub.time > main.time
 ORDER BY sub.time asc
 LIMIT 1) SubColumn,
CAST(TIMESTAMP_DIFF((SELECT MIN(sub.time)
FROM table sub
WHERE sub.time > main.time), main.time, SECOND) AS INT64) duration 
FROM table main
```

but it did not work. The error I get is

*Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.*

Could I get some help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select m.*,
       timestamp_diff(time, next_b_time, second) as duration
from (select m.*,
             min(case when event like 'B%' then time end) over (order by time desc) as next_b_time
      from main m
     )  m
where event like 'A%';
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error here as I did with Mikhail Berlyant's reply

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT event, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(b_time, time, SECOND) duration, b_event
  FROM (
  SELECT event, time,
    LEAD(time) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY time) b_time,
    LEAD(event) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY time) b_event
  FROM (
    SELECT *, 
      COUNTIF(STARTS_WITH(event, 'A')) OVER(ORDER BY time) grp
    FROM `project.dataset.your_table` t
  )
)
WHERE STARTS_WITH(event, 'A')
-- ORDER BY time
```

You can test / play with it using dummy data from your question as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT 'A1' event, TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 1:00:00' time UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B5', TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 2:00:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A3', TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 3:00:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B9', TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 5:00:00' 
)
SELECT event, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(b_time, time, SECOND) duration, b_event
  FROM (
  SELECT event, time,
    LEAD(time) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY time) b_time,
    LEAD(event) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY time) b_event
  FROM (
    SELECT *, 
      COUNTIF(STARTS_WITH(event, 'A')) OVER(ORDER BY time) grp
    FROM `project.dataset.your_table` t
  )
)
WHERE STARTS_WITH(event, 'A')
ORDER BY time
```

with result as

```sql
Row event   duration    b_event  
1   A1      3600        B5   
2   A3      7200        B9
```

Please note: above solution rely on statement in  your question - `B will always happen after A` so if you have sequence as below

```sql
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT 'A1' event, TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 1:00:00' time UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A2', TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 1:30:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B5', TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 2:00:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A3', TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 3:00:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B9', TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 5:00:00' 
)
```

result will be

```sql
Row event   duration    b_event  
1   A1      null        null     
2   A2      1800        B5   
3   A3      7200        B9
```

If you need to address this  - try below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT 'A1' event, TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 1:00:00' time UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A2', TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 1:30:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B5', TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 2:00:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A3', TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 3:00:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B9', TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 5:00:00' 
)
SELECT event, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(b_time, time, SECOND) duration, b_event
FROM (
  SELECT event, time, type, grp,
    FIRST_VALUE(event) OVER(ORDER BY grp RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) b_event,
    FIRST_VALUE(time) OVER(ORDER BY grp RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) b_time
  FROM (
    SELECT event, time, SUBSTR(event, 1, 1) type,
      COUNTIF(STARTS_WITH(event, 'B')) OVER(ORDER BY time) grp
    FROM `project.dataset.your_table` t
  )
)
WHERE STARTS_WITH(event, 'A')
ORDER BY time
```

this version will return

```sql
Row event   duration    b_event  
1   A1      3600        B5   
2   A2      1800        B5   
3   A3      7200        B9
```

Comment: I'm getting another BigQuery error here:

_Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Sort operator used for OVER(ORDER BY) used too much memory._

My table has 38 million rows. Possible resolutions?

Comment: When ordering large amount of data - it is recommended to also use PARTITION BY in your OVER() statement. Depends on nature of your data, you can use for example daily partitioning by adding `PARTITION BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM time)` of course in this case you will miss event crossing the boundary of the day

Comment: Here you will find some guidelines on [how to generally deal with the `resourcesExceeded` error](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#resourcesExceeded). In your case, given the large amount of rows you are querying, `ORDER BY` is a big limitation. You can try with  `PARTITION BY` as @MikhailBerlyant suggested, or with `LIMIT`.